# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 on Mac OS X when compiling using LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-gcc, llvm-ir

I am trying to make the compiler in this project using LLVM shipped in Mac OS X Yosemite and getting the following error mentioned in this Issue on Github https://github.com/lsegal/my_toy_compiler/issues/17

When running the `make all` command, it seems to throw an error saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LLVMInitializeX86Target", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in main.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in main.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in main.o
```

I found out that these are defined in this header file `/usr/local/include/llvm/Config/config.h`

```
/* LLVM name for the native Target init function, if available */
#define LLVM_NATIVE_TARGET LLVMInitializeX86Target

/* LLVM name for the native TargetInfo init function, if available */
#define LLVM_NATIVE_TARGETINFO LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo

/* LLVM name for the native target MC init function, if available */
#define LLVM_NATIVE_TARGETMC LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC
```

I am building this using `g++` compiler and getting an error when compiling with `llvm-g++` compiler. Does anyone know what the issue is? Is LLVM not installed correctly on my Mac?

```
~/Personal> llvm-g++ --version
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libltdl.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/../../..//usr/local/llvm-gcc-install/bin/i686-apple-darwin8-g++-4.0.1
  Reason: image not found
```

EDIT:

I also have Xcode Beta 6 installed so not sure if that is messing with the llvm-g++ and using OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Probably forgot to add dependent library.
Add these and try again

-lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMMC -lLLVMObject -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport